# Web Scraping Features TripAdvisor

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** the TripAdvisor site about Hotels from my city (Brasília - https://www.tripadvisor.com.br/Hotels-g303322-Brasilia_Federal_District-Hotels.html). Then, I want to scrape the hotel's features, like (Free Wifi (Wi-fi Gratuito), Piscina (Pool), etc) but my code is scraping all the features separated. There are 30 hotels, and in the end, I got 61 features because my code can't concatenate this for the respective hotel name.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com.br/Hotels-g303322-Brasilia_Federal_District-Hotels.html')

bsobj = soup(html.content, 'lxml')

hotel = []
for name in bsobj.findAll('div', {'class':'listing_title'}):
    hotel.append(name.text.strip())
hotel #30 Hotel

caracteristicas = []
for caracteristica in bsobj.findAll('span', {'class':'text'}):
    caracteristicas.append(caracteristica.text.strip())
caracteristicas #61 features (caracteristicas)
```

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

try iterating over this main div, then pulling the hotel name and amenities from here:

```
<div class="prw_rup prw_meta_hsx_responsive_listing ui_section listItem" data-prwidget-name="meta_hsx_responsive_listing" data-prwidget-init="handlers" data-no-pt-mw="true" data-mlv="true">
```